# I am unable to share image using sharing intent and cannot create directory

Tags: java, android, android-intent, share

i am unable to pass the image using share intent.The app runs but when i try to send image to a friend in whatsApp it says "**Sharing failed, please try again"** and on sharing with gmail it says "**Cannot attach empty file**" .I have also set permission in Manifests. I guess there is some issue in creating file or maybe the path.

please Check the below code:

```
share.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {



            Bitmap icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), img);
            Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            sharingIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
            sharingIntent.setType("image/*");
            ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            icon.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
             File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)+ File.separator + "temporary_file.jpg");
           // File f1=Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);

            //File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/save_picture", "temporary_file.jpg");

            try {
              f.createNewFile();
               // f.mkdir();
                f.createNewFile();
                FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(f);
                fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

            }
           // sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("content://" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()));
             sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,Uri.parse("content:///sdcard/temporary_file.jpg"));
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share via: "));


        }
    });
```

Comment: Is there any stacktrace in logcat?

Comment: No, App runs and it does not crashes. There is no exception or error seen in logcat.

Comment: Where is stored your image you are deciding as bitmap? In the filesystem or memory?

Comment: Hum, seems like a runtime permissions issue

Comment: @MarcEstrada actually the img passed in Bitmap is the Integer value of the image and even i can see the image getting converted to bitmap from debugging mode.i guess it's something related to file .

Comment: @E.Abdel Can you elaborate? i am new to this.Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Please check my answer

Comment: @Navin I think your URI is wrong, take a look to my answer and tell me if it works for you.

Comment: @Navin Found solution?

Answer (score 1):

I think the URI is malformed. Try this:

```
Uri.fromFile(file);
```

instead of

```
Uri.parse("content:///sdcard/temporary_file.jpg"); // Here probably file path is wrong
```

Using `Uri.fromFile` you ensures that the file URI is correct.

If your targetSdkVersion is 24+ you need to use content:// instead of file://. To migrate, checkout this question.

[android.os.FileUriExposedException: file:///storage/emulated/0/test.txt exposed beyond app through Intent.getData()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38200282/android-os-fileuriexposedexception-file-storage-emulated-0-test-txt-exposed)

Comment: Error :   android.os.FileUriExposedException: file:///storage/emulated/0/Pictures/temporary_file.jpg exposed beyond app through ClipData.Item.getUri()

Comment: Ok, you are targeting 24+. Take a look to my answer, I've just edited it with a solution.

Comment: But not using the right way. Your Uri path is wrong

Comment: i tried the file provider method and still while sharing image to whatsApp there is a toast "File format is not supported" 
could u edit my code what Uri path is correct ?

Answer (score 0):

For android 6 and higher, adding permissions in manifest is not enough, you have to request for permission at the runtime. For example, for external storage permission, you have to do this :

```
if (checkSelfPermission(android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    // permission granted, you can write external storage
}
```

If is not granted, you have to request the permission :

```
final int READ_STORAGE_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 1212;            
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity) context, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);

}
```

For reading external storage, you have to remplace `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` by `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`

**EDIT :**

Override  onRequestPermissionsResult in your activity :

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] results) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, results);
    if(PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED == grantResults[0]){

        //The user accepted the permissions requests, you can do your stuffs here
    }
}
```

You can find more informations [here](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting)

Comment: what is the API level of the testing device?

Comment: getting this errors:     E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.apple.wallpapershd, PID: 6274
    java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:608)
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:643)
        at com.example.apple.wallpapershd.WallpaperFullScreen$2.onClick(WallpaperFullScreen.java:94)

Comment: the testing device is of API  26